# Django: production app on Heroku cant find templates with "path" urlpattern

Tags: django, heroku

I´m having my production site on Heroku.

The app can find templates defined with `url` in the `urlpatterns` of the `urls.py` file.

Like: `url(r'^contactreport/$', views.ContactosView, name="contactos"),`

But not the ones defined with `path`.

Like: `path('inventario/', views.InventarioView, name="inventario"),`

**Settings**

This is my static folder config in `settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

This is my middleware (but I think it´s not the problem).

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**The error I get**

When I try the links to thos pages I get:

> TemplateDoesNotExist
>
> django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
>   /app/templates/catalog/tareas.html (Source does not exist)

The html template exists.

**The full traceback**

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   https://afternoon-wildwood-39943.herokuapp.com/catalog/tareas/
>
> Django Version: 2.1.3 Python Version: 3.7.0 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig',  'rest_framework',  'django.urls', 
>   'django.contrib.humanize',  'catalog.templatetags'] Installed
>   Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Template loader postmortem Django tried loading these templates, in
>   this order:
>
> Using engine django:
>       * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/templates/catalog/tareas.html (Source does not exist)
>       * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/catalog/tareas.html
>   (Source does not exist)
>       * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/catalog/tareas.html
>   (Source does not exist)
>       * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/catalog/templates/catalog/tareas.html (Source does not exist)
>       * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/catalog/tareas.html
>   (Source does not exist)
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/catalog/views.py" in TareasView
>     630.         'mis_tareas_atrasadas': mis_tareas_atrasadas,
>
> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py"
>   in render
>     36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py"
>   in render_to_string
>     61.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
>
> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py"
>   in get_template
>     19.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
>
> Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /catalog/tareas/ Exception
>   Value: catalog/tareas.html

**One of the views that gives problems**

```
@login_required
def TareasView(request):
    tareas_filter_form = TareasFilterForm(request.POST)
    tareas_form = FormularioTareas(request.POST)
    tareas = Tareas.objects.all()
    tareas = tareas.order_by("-fecha_creacion")
    mis_tareas_por_hacer = tareas.filter(resuelto=False).count()

    desde = date.today() - timedelta(days=365)
    hasta = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    mis_tareas_atrasadas = tareas.filter(fecha_limite__range=[desde, hasta]).count()

    if request.method == "POST" and 'filtrar_tareas' in request.POST:
        tareas_filter_form = TareasFilterForm(request.POST)
        if tareas_filter_form.is_valid():
            estatus_resuelto = tareas_filter_form.cleaned_data["estatus_resuelto"]
            destinatario = tareas_filter_form.cleaned_data["destinatario"]
            busca_titulo = tareas_filter_form.cleaned_data["busca_titulo"]
            if destinatario:
                tareas = tareas.filter(destinatario=destinatario)

            if estatus_resuelto != "Todas":
                tareas = tareas.filter(resuelto=estatus_resuelto)

            tareas = tareas.filter(titulo__icontains=busca_titulo)

    return render(request, 'catalog/tareas.html', {
        'tareas_form': tareas_form,
        'tareas_filter_form': tareas_filter_form,
        'tareas': tareas,
        'mis_tareas_por_hacer': mis_tareas_por_hacer,
        'mis_tareas_atrasadas': mis_tareas_atrasadas,

    })
```

Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you type `from django.urls import path` in your urls.py?

Comment: @Aurélien Yes I did.

Comment: What do you mean, it can't find the templates? What do template have to do with this? What *exactly* happens when you go to that URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just updated the post

Comment: If you get `TemplateDoesNotExist`, then please show the view that is failing, the full error message, and the project layout. It will make no difference to this error if you use `path()` or `url()`.

Comment: Since you are using Heroku, make sure that the template has been checked in and pushed to Heroku.

Comment: @Alasdair I´m deploying through Github and I can confirm I have the files there. Don´t really know how to check that in Heroku.

Comment: And when I run `git push heroku master` it says everything is up to date.

Comment: You haven't added any of the other things I mentioned, so I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: @Alasdair Sorry, was in a hurry yesterday and didn´t see the prior message. Just updated the post. I don´t know how to print the full project layout. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using linux or macOS, then you can print out the project layout with `tree`. If you can't do that, please give the full path of the `tareas.html` template that is not found, and show your `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: @Alasdair Maybe it´s easier if you have a look at the Github repository? [link](https://github.com/FranGhelfi/kinemed-production)

Comment: Yes, I can see the problem having looked at your repo. You have saved the template as `Tareas.html`, but you are using `tareas.html` in your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is trying to render `'catalog/tareas.html'`

```
return render(request, 'catalog/tareas.html', {...})
```

But your template name is `catalog/Tareas.html`.

If you are developing on a case-insensitive file system then you won't see any error in development.

However, in production, Heroku is running on a case-sensitive file system, so the template is not found.

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much. I was going crazy.